# Selinium-webdriver ul inside of the list view unable to automate

Tags: selenium

```
<div id="from-list" class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset k-state-border-up" data-role="popup" style="height: auto; display: block; font-size: 16px; font-family: "TR",arial; font-stretch: normal; font-style: normal; font-weight: 500; line-height: 23.2px; width: 206.6px; transform: translateY(0px); position: absolute;">
<ul id="from_listbox" class="k-list k-reset" unselectable="on" style="overflow: auto; height: auto;" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="false" aria-live="polite">
<li class="k-item" unselectable="on" data-idx="0" role="option" tabindex="-1">pr.sud@en.com</li>
<li class="k-item" unselectable="on" data-idx="1" role="option" tabindex="-1">pra.melu@en.com</li>
<li class="k-item" unselectable="on" data-idx="2" role="option" tabindex="-1">prast.bha@en.com</li>
<li class="k-item" unselectable="on" data-idx="3" role="option" tabindex="-1">prp@savant.com</li>
</ul>
</div>



I try to automate above code its not working
```

I used this code

```
    dr.findElement(By.id("from-list")).findElement(By.id("from_listbox")).click(); 
    List<WebElement> liList = dr.findElements(By.id("from_listbox"));
     liList.get(0).click(); 
     liList.get(1).click();
```

Please let me know if any of have idea about that

Comment: automate what? whats the error?

Comment: see my answer below. next time it could be an good idea to debug the code before posting on SO :P -  liList.get(1).click(); throws a IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int liSize = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='from_listbox']/li")).size();
for(int j = 1; j <= liSize; j++) {
    String liLocator = String.format(".//*[@id='from_listbox']/li[%d]", j);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(liLocator)).click();
}
```

Comment: Yea I accept this code, This code working well and Thanks for your solution. This code used i did little change on my code. Its working fine my code i added below

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at the end of the XPATH before i didn't add (/li)
After i saw ur mesage i add that (/li). Its working fine.

List  listItems = dr.findElements(By.xpath(".//*@id='from_listbox']/li"));
listItems2.get(0).click();